# Probability of optimal selection with 2 selection stages

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I need to make a random selection with 2 selection stages. In the first stage, I have a list of N choices. Each choice has 2 choices in second stage. You randomly select one of the N choices in the first stage, and randomly select between the 2 choices in the second stage. What is the probability that after the 2 choices are made the selection was optimal? Also, if I have a set of utilities that I want to maximise at each stage (maximise 1st one, then maximise 2nd one), what is the probability that I will get an optimal choice?

Comment: There are in total $2N$ possible outcomes? Are they equiprobable, and is exactly one of them marked as "optimal"? Then the answer is $\frac1{2N}$ of course.

Comment: Can you explain how did you get that answer?

Comment: If there are $2N$ possible outcomes that all have the same probability of appearance and exactly one of them will appear, then each of them must have probability $\frac1{2N}$ to appear. This because the summation of the probabilities of these mutually exclusive and covering events must be $1$.